# Is it possible to change the h2 tag on the dayGridMonth view heading?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The dayGridMonth view with Fullcalendar shows the month and year in a h2 tag in the headerToolbar, and I want to change it to h3 - is this possible?  I'm using Fullcalendar 5.

Comment: Well you could write code to manually update the HTML after the calendar is loaded, but there's nothing you can do via the fullCalendar options no. Another alternative is to add some CSS such that the H2 element is styled to have smaller text so it looks more like what it would be as a h3

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted that as a feature request. As you say it's easy to style it in CSS or update the HTML after loading, but for website accessibility purposes it would be ideal if you could choose the heading level.